# Materialize CSS different column style for the width of browser?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to make a website with materialize css that is fully responsive for a product that my friend is making. I have a layout in materialize for mobile and for desktop but I don't know how to make them shift columns when the page gets to a certain size. The mobile code is just all `col s12` but on the desktop version it is more split. Any help or input would be appreciated.

Thanks again, Optimistic.

Comment: You need to post your code (ideally a working example). https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The answer given by @ctumturk is perfectly valid. You've gotta use ```<div class = "col s12 m8 l4">```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should design your page for each screen size differently. Materialize CSS gives you the opportunity to use use different classes for different screen sizes.

By defining 
`<div class = "col s12">` mean you use 12 columns for every screen size. I think what you are looking for is something like `<div class = "col s12 m8 l4">`

You can get detailed information about grid system from the referance below:

http://materializecss.com/grid.html

Also, you might want to check for bootstrap as well. It is very easy to use in Visual Studio 2013.

If you have enough time (a day or so) there is a useful training in MVA explaining the grid system, responsive web design using Bootstrap which is completely free. You can find it in:

[Building responsive UI with using Bootstrap](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/building-responsive-ui-with-bootstrap-8378)

Hope this helps you

Cagri

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to make different view for different platforms.

This is best made by @media(){} in CSS, which is situated for this problem>

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Shortly you define @media for width you need and give different attributes to your columns.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px;) {

#columns {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px;) {

#columns {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%;
}

}
```

Will make your columns next each other on tablet and desktop and under each other on mobile platform.

Otherwise, Bootstrap is a good option how to do this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should refrence their documentation (http://materializecss.com/grid.html)

Basically, there are three main settings: small (s), medium (m) and large (l) within grids. You can choose to hide content on different screen sizes also.